# Calculating the total return on an Interest Rate Swap (with 1 year of duration)

Tags: time-series, derivatives

Say I am the fixed rate payer on an interest rate swap and have 1 year of duration of exposure.

When I entered into the IRS (say yesterday), the quoted rate on Bloomberg was 15%.

Say tomorrow the quoted rate on Bloomberg falls to 14%. Is my return 1%? In other words do I take the difference between yesterday's rate and today's rate to calculate the return on 1 year of exposure?

Am trying to then compound these to then get a cumulative return chart. This would assume I balance each day to maintain 1 year of constant duration, correct?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don’t think you can straightforwardly talk about “return” on unfunded positions such as swaps.

Comment: ...maybe Profit/Loss would be more straightforward...

Comment: Thanks! How would you calculate P&L on and interest rate swap?